# How to prevent enter data into an ajax combobox control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

  <asp:ComboBox ID="service_list" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="CL_DESCRIPTION" 
                    DataValueField="CL_ID" ondatabound="MyListDataBound"
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="RedTypeComboBoxStyle" >
                        </asp:ComboBox >
```

how can i prohibit the user from entering data in the textbox of the ajax combobox?

Note: i don't wanna use a dropdown list because i'm using css to change the design of the ajax combobox but i just need to prevent the user from entering data in the combobox..

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DropDownStyle** - Determines whether the user is allowed to enter text that does not match an item in the list, and whether the list is always displayed.
If "DropDownList" is specified, users are not allowed to enter text that does not match an item in the list.
 When "DropDown" (the default value) is specified, any text is allowed. 
If "Simple" is specified, any text is allowed and the list is always displayed regardless of the AutoCompleteMode property value.

References:- 
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_ComboBox.ashx